# Can Protobuf dynamically parse a field?

Tags: protocol-buffers

File `my_protocol.proto`:

```
Message MyProtocol {
    required int32 protocolId = 1;
    required **unknownType** protocolBody = 2; 
}
```

I want to parse protocolBody according to protocolId.

For example,

`protocolId = 10001` represents a login event, then the `protocolBody` should be a login message and can be parsed by `login.proto`.

I don't know which type should be set on the **unknownType**.

Answer (score 0):

Protocol buffers parses the whole message in the one go.

You could have a message

```
Message MyProtocolGetId {
    required int32 protocolId = 1;
}
```

Parse that then reparse with the correct message id. Alternatively the ProtocolBody could be stored as bytes and passed seperately

Comment: Thank you. It seems not necessary to use protobuf sending the protocolId. I'd like to send protocolId directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can fake it, but it will be awkward. You have to use optional fields, and indicate which one if present using a flag. Make sure to double check that the field is set in your receiver code:

```
Message OneOfManyTypes {
    required int32 kind = 1;
    optional MessageType1 ty1 = 2;
    optional MessageType2 ty2 = 3;
    ...
}
```